# How to read raw block from an USB storage device with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, filesystems, usb

I'm dealing with an USB storage device that contains a proprietary file system. So, I need to read these device's 512 bytes blocks to implement a viewer for this filesystem.

How should I go about this? Is there some material on it using Delphi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hate components so here is some code

```
 var 
    RawMBR : array [0..511] of byte;
    btsIO  : DWORD;
 begin
  hDevice := CreateFile('\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1', GENERIC_READ,
      FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    if hDevice <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    begin
      SetFilePointer(hDevice,512 * 0,nil,FILE_BEGIN); // replace 0 with sector that you wish to read
      ReadFile(hDevice, RawMBR[0], 512, btsIO, nil);
      CloseHandle(hDevice);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: How to use this code for a drive(like c:\, d:\ and ...)? Is It Possible to help me? (^_^)

Comment: @ShaahinAshayeri on createfile use \\.\C:

Comment: @opc0de Can i use the same approach to write raw ?

Comment: @Bianca shure only you need Admin rights to do it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [RawDiskAccess](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=253) component, source for Delphi 7 [here](http://www.torry.net/vcl/filedrv/diskaccess/RawDiskAccess_v1-1.zip)

Comment: Looks promising, but doesn't compile with Delphi 2010. Gonna try to fix the source.

Answer (score 2):

Read it just like any other disk when doing a raw read access. You just need the first sector

For Delphi you can look at:

http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=253

Physical Disk Access (may work for you)
Raw Disk Access (may work for you)
TDiskIO (too old, works only under w9x)

Comment: Those components won't compile on Delphi 2010 (and probably all Delphis above 2009) and porting them is giving me a hard time. I will try directly through the Windows API for now if no other solution is proposed and post and answer with it when it works.

Answer (score 1):

We have [RawDisk](http://www.eldos.com/rawdisk/) product which provides read and write access to raw partitions under XP, Vista and Windows 7 (there exist certain security restrictions when using Windows API and RawDisk lets you bypass those restrictions). Code is available for all versions of Delphi from Delphi 5 to Delphi XE (XE2 support will be added in a couple of days).