# Ho to read ISO 9660 in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, iso9660

I'm currently working on a project and need to know when a DVD was burned (Date of day that DVD was burned). As far as I searched and looked for, found out all data like this are following ISO 9660 format, but I couldn't find how to access or read it, also tried some component packs and libraries related, but none of them was working as i expected and needed.

also found this link: [How to find out when a disc (DVD) has been written/burned?](https://superuser.com/questions/559031/how-to-find-out-when-a-disc-dvd-has-been-written-burned) but I couldn't find a way to use them in Delphi.
How its working?

Comment: Some info here, [How to find out when a disc (DVD) has been written/burned?](http://superuser.com/a/559089).

Comment: @LURD, already have seen it... thanks for mention it, i should do it, my bad.... the problem is i cant find a way to use them in Delphi...

Comment: Can't you just read the raw data from the disk at the correct location? [How to read raw block from an USB storage device with Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7835797/576719).

Comment: i have no idea, does it work same? i dont think so

Comment: @LU RD: The first link points to a solutuon for Linux or Unix. Not easy to translate to Delphi, indeed. The second looks promising, but where to look?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, The ISO file format is the same for all operating systems. A raw read on correct location is fine. I will post my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the link to this answer: [How to find out when a disc (DVD) has been written/burned?](https://superuser.com/a/559089) gives where to read the date and time information on the disk:

Reading 16 characters plus one additional byte starting with position 33582 gives the DVD creation time as:

> YYYYMMDDHHMMSSCCO

where CC are centiseconds and O is the offset from GMT in 15 minute intervals, stored as an 8-bit integer (two's complement representation).

Following code can be used to read (see also [How to read raw block from an USB storage device with Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7835797/576719)):

```
function GetDVDCreationDate: String;
// Sector size is 2048 on ISO9660 optical data discs
const
  sector_size = 2048;
  rdPos = (33582 DIV sector_size);  // 33582
  rdOfs = (33582 MOD sector_size) - 1;
var
  RawMBR  : array [0..sector_size-1] of byte;
  btsIO   : DWORD;
  hDevice : THandle;
  i       : Integer;
  GMTofs  : ShortInt;
begin
  Result := '';
  hDevice := CreateFile('\\.\E:', GENERIC_READ,  // Select drive 
    FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
  if hDevice <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    SetFilePointer(hDevice,sector_size * rdPos,nil,FILE_BEGIN);
    ReadFile(hDevice, RawMBR[0], sector_size, btsIO, nil);
    if (btsIO = sector_size) then begin
      for i := 0 to 15 do begin
        Result := Result + AnsiChar(RawMBR[rdOfs+i]);
      end;
      GMTofs := ShortInt(RawMBR[rdOfs+16]);  // Handle GMT offset if important
    end;
    CloseHandle(hDevice);
  end;
end;
```

---

Note that reading raw data from the disc must start on even sector size positions. For [ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) disks, the sector size is 2048.

Comment: it was nice one, thanks for it, did give me a clue at least... but it doesn't return correct answer, it will return a string with random chars like "#$%" or something like this... i think the problem is sector size positions, but as you said for ISO 9660 its 2048.

Comment: as i looked in ISO pages there are many standards for Optical storage devices - Including CD and magneto-optical devices (MO): http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_ics_browse.htm?ICS1=35&ICS2=220&ICS3=30&published=on
can them be burned in other formats than ISO 9660? if yes so how can it be identified?

Comment: @Armin, tested my answer on a couple of writable data DVD's, and it worked fine. Note that you need to identify the correct drive label.

Comment: i was aware for drive label

Comment: just decided to play with your code, i assumed problem is sector size (seems i was wrong), for checking other sector sizes i added a integer parameter to your function and moved rdPos and rdOfs from const to var for being able modify them in run-time and some little modifies... as i compiled and did run the project (start with 2048 as beginning the test) it just worked correct and perfect. thanks to you but i did not change anything major... how did it work? i couldn't figure it out how these changes affect the code, i'll post them as an answer to be easier to read

Comment: @Armin I tested the code earlier to day and it worked correctly as is. I noted though that there was no error indication when the DVD was not ready, and in such a case the function returned some spurios characters. Maybe that was the case for you too at first. A DVD needs time to get up and running.

Comment: @LURD Great!+1 I suggest however a small addition after `ReadFile()` and before the for loop:  `if btsIO <> 2048 then Result := 'Error' else`. At least a `Result := '';` in the beginning.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, thanks for the suggestion. Added to answer.

Comment: @LURD, i did mind the time for DVD to getting up and running, here is an image of running two functions together. left one is your original code (in this case is returning nothing, look where the cursor is...) and the right one, as you can see is modified one:  https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=890D277CE1004419!384&authkey=!AMsfhhp5FWHheJI&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @LU RD answer, here is his code with some very little modifications:

```
function GetDVDCreationDate(sectorSize:integer): String;
// Sector size is 2048 on ISO9660 optical data discs
var
  RawMBR  : array [0..2047] of byte;
  btsIO   : DWORD;
  hDevice : THandle;
  i       : Integer;
  GMTofs  : ShortInt;
  rdPos, rdOfs: integer;

begin
  rdPos := (33582 DIV sectorSize);  // 33582
  rdOfs := (33582 MOD sectorSize) - 1;

  hDevice := CreateFile('\\.\H:', GENERIC_READ,  // Select drive
    FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
  if hDevice <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    SetFilePointer(hDevice,sectorSize * rdPos,nil,FILE_BEGIN);
    ReadFile(hDevice, RawMBR[0], sectorSize, btsIO, nil);
    for i := 0 to 15 do begin
      Result := Result + AnsiChar(RawMBR[rdOfs+i]);
    end;
    GMTofs := ShortInt(RawMBR[rdOfs+16]);  // Handle GMT offset if important
    CloseHandle(hDevice);
  end;
end;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure Tfrm_main.btn_creationReadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  memo_dataLog.Lines.Add(GetDVDCreationDate(StrToInt(edit_sSize.Text)))
end;
```